# adding an element to the end of a list, scheme

Tags: scheme

I'm stuck on something I know is trivial but I just don't know what to do. I'm converting a string to a list, changing the list a bit, and then converting it back to a string.

I'm translating words into pig latin, but I'm having trouble adding the "ay" to the end of a word. I know how to take the first element of a list and send it to the back, but for some reason my code won't add the "ay" as well. I've appended to lists before in scheme, it was relatively straightforward, but I can't figure out why it isn't working here and I've tried a few different methods.

Here is the code:

```
(define (member? item seq)
  (sequence-ormap (lambda (x)
                    (equal? item x))
                  seq))

(define (vowel? letter)
  (member? letter '(a e i o u)))

(define (first-to-last x) (append (cdr x) (list (car x))))

(define (piglatin wd)
  (define stringlist (string->list wd))
  (cond
    [(vowel? (car stringlist)) (append 'yay stringlist)]
    [else (define pigstringlist (first-to-last stringlist)) (append pigstringlist '(ay)) (list->string pigstringlist)])
  )
```

I hope that looks all right, besides the inability to append to the end of the list. I feel like I'm missing something simple, but I'm trying to learn scheme coming from a C/Java background and it's these little things that are huge time consumers. If anyone sees anything I'd be very grateful. I could use some advice and trimming down this code a bit too, because it seems a little much to me.

Here's the output, on `"home"`

```
(piglatin "home")
"omeh"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(define (piglatin wd)
  (define stringlist (string->list wd))
  (cond
    [(vowel? (car stringlist)) (append 'yay stringlist)]
    [else (define pigstringlist (first-to-last stringlist)) 
          (append pigstringlist '(ay))    ;;
          (list->string pigstringlist)]))
```

You compute a new list with the list `'(ay)` appended, but:

1. `'(ay)` is a list containing a single symbol. Here, you are supposed to manipulate list of characters, which are different. See for example:

   ```
   (string->list "wow")
   => (#\w #\o #\w)
   ```
2. The result of the `append` function is discarded. Remember that `append` does not modify the existing list. Thus, the value returned in the `else` case is `pigstringlist`, a.k.a. `(first-to-last stringlist)`.

The whole expression in `else` could be (first version):

```
...
[else (list->string 
        (append (first-to-last stringlist)
                '(#\a #\y)))]...
```

The same goes for `'yay`, above, which is not a list.
You are manipulating strings using list functions, but you could use string-related functions, like [string-append](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/strings.html#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._string-append%29%29):

```
(define (pig-latin wd)
  (cond
    [(vowel? (string-ref wd 0)) (string-append "yay" wd)]
    [else (string-append (first-to-last wd) "ay")]))
```

Of course, `first-to-last` should be redefined because it expects a list.
One way to implement it would be:

```
(define (first-to-last word)
  (string-append (substring word 1)
                 (substring word 0 1)))
```

When you define `vowel?`, the membership test always fails because once again you compare letters, which are characters, with symbols, which are identifiers. You should probably take into consideration uppercase letters:

```
(define (vowel? letter)
  (member letter '(#\a #\e #\i #\o #\u #\y) char-ci-=?))
```

I am using the existing [member](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html?q=member#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt%29._member%29%29) function, which accepts an equality predicate. Here, the function compares characters case-insensitively.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I would not convert the string to a list and back. I would just play with the string directly. Here's the solution approach I have in mind:

1. Downcase the string.
2. Find the longest run of initial consonants in the string.
3. If the consonant run is empty, then simply append "yay" to the end of the string.
4. Otherwise, take the substring after the consonant run, then append the consonant run and "ay".
5. If the original string started with an uppercase letter, then titlecase the resulting string. (This means that if the original word were in all-caps, this will do the wrong thing. Too bad. Less shouting for the win.)

Here's the code (requires SRFIs [13](http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-13/srfi-13.html) and [14](http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-14/srfi-14.html)):

```
(define vowels (char-set #\a #\e #\i #\o #\u))
(define (pig-latin word)
  (define downcased (string-downcase word))
  (define index (string-index downcased vowels))
  (define result (if (zero? (or index 0))
                     (string-append downcased "yay")
                     (string-append (substring downcased index)
                                    (substring downcased 0 index)
                                    "ay")))
  (if (and (not (zero? (string-length word)))
           (char-upper-case? (string-ref word 0)))
      (string-titlecase result)
      result))
```